# Why is my Volley request returning 0?

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

As the title suggests, I am having a little trouble with my `Volley` `onResponse` script. In the script I am passing `POST` data to my PHP script which would then return a value of either 0 or 1 but is only returning 0. I will also include my PHP script, although I am certain that is not the problem.

```
private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://192.168.0.7/login.php";

public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

private EditText loginEmail;
private EditText loginPassword;

private Button loginButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    TextView registerLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.registerLink);

    registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
        }
    });

    loginEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    loginPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);

    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void loginUser() {
    final String password = loginPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = loginEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getBody(){
            Map<String,String> body = new HashMap<String, String>();
            body.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            body.put(KEY_EMAIL,email);
            return body;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == loginButton){
        loginUser();
    }
}
```

}

Here is the PHP script.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

require_once('dbConnect.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
$data = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die('Error');

if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
    $response = 1;
    echo(json_encode($response));
} else {
    $response = 0;
    echo(json_encode($response));
}
```

}

Comment: Pls post more Android code, how did you define the request?

Comment: Like so....         final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
. The PHP script is receiving the variables fine.

Comment: How did you set your POST data in that request?

Comment: @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
                params.put(KEY_EMAIL,email);
                return params;
            }

Comment: Use `getBody` instead `getParams`

Comment: I've updated my post to include the full java script as changing the param to body has returned to following error "Error:(80, 42) error: getBody() in <anonymous com.example.matt.heu.LoginActivity$4> cannot override getBody() in Request
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public"

Comment: You should change `protected Map<String,String> getBody()` to `public Map<String,String> getBody()`

Comment: Ok I'm a moron. Turns out the database had duplicate records causing the PHP to run the code inside the else statement. Sorry for wasting your time.